# How to disable script for some objects in prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've a moving script in prefab called "player". So, my script works with camera and canvas too. But I need this script only for 'body'.

[[image]]

Yes, I can't move this script into 'body', because I need this script for `Rigidbody2D`, Network Transform, and etc. Simply put, my script is locating in "player" prefab, I can't move it - that's all.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeedup;
    public float moveSpeeddown;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    public bool moveup;
    public bool movedown;
    public bool rotateleft;
    public bool rotateright;
    void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) || moveup)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * moveSpeedup * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || movedown)
        {
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * moveSpeeddown * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || rotateleft)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || rotateright)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 my script is locating in "player" prefab and it works for camera, canvas, and body. But I want, that my script works only for 'body' object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeedup;
    public float moveSpeeddown;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    public bool moveup;
    public bool movedown;
    public bool rotateleft;
    public bool rotateright;
    public Transform body;
    void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) || moveup)
        {
            body.Translate(Vector3.right * moveSpeedup * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || movedown)
        {
            body.Translate(-Vector3.right * moveSpeeddown * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || rotateleft)
        {
            body.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || rotateright)
        {
            body.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit unclear but if I'm understanding you correctly, you want to the movement script only on the "Body" object, not the parent, "Player" object.

You *can* move it, and simply have the Body object find its' parent object and get those things (Rigidbody2D, Transform, etc.) from that. Something like...

```
GameObject parentObject = childObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
```

You can also, within your child object, create public variables for your prefab and set them to their parent-prefab attributes.

Comment: I said that I can't move, bc I have some functions in "player" object. If I move all functions, it WON'T work. Also I edited my post with additional moving code.